# Valid visa ... Blue Card new issue in Gemany

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, germany, blue-card

I had applied for the extension of myBlue Card eAT at the immigration office in Stuttgart. The new extended Blue Card eAT is now available for collection at the immigration office in Stuttgart (confirmation from the immigration office is on email).

Since I am currently in India, I will not be able to collect it until I return.

Unfortunately, I failed to correctly read the expiry date on my current Blue Card eAT, whose expiry date is December 4th, 2023.

I called the Frankfurt border control police. They confirmed new visa is valid until 2027 in their stored personal data and confirmed that I can travel back to Germany with the existing blue card (which has expired) and the letter from the Stuttgart immigration office.

However, I am not allowed to travel on the expired document (BlueCard) as per the Embassy of the Federal Republic of Germany and advised me to apply for a Return visa (Wiedereinreise).

Can anyone please tell me what I can do. I have booked my flight from Delhi I have no idea should I travel or should I not.
I am at urge losing my Job in Germany due to this, I have also try to connect with visa embassy in Mumbai, Bangalore and other places got no response they don't even pick my call. Can anyone help.

Comment: Your biggest obstacle will likely be the airline you travel to Germany with. If they aren't satisfied with your eingangsbestaetigung (letter from immigration authority) they might deny boarding. Call the airline and ask.

Comment: Thank you soo much .. I will try to connect with them.

Comment: Can anyone in Germany pick up the new card and send it to you?

Comment: @mintay: Not unless they were given power of attorney.

Comment: Yeah... I have tried this.. but germany embassy is not ready to issue to anyone,despite giving power of attorney. I have even try to call Airlines .. they were helpless.